# Is it possible to share a custom xaml build definition with a git and a tfvc team project?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

We are trying to migrate from tfvc to git and the most difficult part would be to recreate the builds.

The codebase is still the same so is there any possible way to share these custom definitions or atleast copy paste most of it into a new build definition?

Even just a straight up no would be really helpful in moving things forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you migrate to new build system. Regarding TFVC team project, it can have git repositories and you can switch Repository type (e.g. TFVC, git) directly, the build steps/tasks can be the same.

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's not going to be possible to migrate without redoing the builds. This answers all the questions I had. I'll accept this by the end of the day if there isn't a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the common stuff into a custom build activity. Really though, the best option is to migrate to the new build system and leave XAML behind.

Comment: That's the idea if this doesn't pan out. Problem is there is like 22 builds we'd have to recreate. I've got two questions though. What do you mean when you say custom build activity? And would it be possible to have builds for tfvc and git at the same time with the new build system?